# How to create an JSON array using node-csvtojson?

Tags: node.js, json, csv, node-streams

When using [node-csvtojson](https://github.com/Keyang/node-csvtojson) how can I output data as a json array?

```
const request = require("request");
const csv = require("csvtojson");
const fs = require("fs");

const readStream = request.get("http://www.example.com/some.csv");
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream("./some.json");
const converter = csv({
  includeColumns: /Column3|Column2/
});

readStream.pipe(converter).pipe(writeStream);
```

Assuming the following data structure:

```
Column1,Column2,Column3
1,2,3
one,two,three
```

I would expect the output file to contain:

```
[
  { "Column2": "2", "Column3": "3" },
  { "Column2": "two", "Column3": "three" }
]
```

I actually get the following:

```
{ "Column2": "2", "Column3": "3" }
{ "Column2": "two", "Column3": "three" }
```

How to I ensure that I get a JSON array as output?

I am aware of [this issue](https://github.com/Keyang/node-csvtojson/issues/107) but I notice that `toArrayString` has been removed from the api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of asking I am unable to do what I want with the `csvtojson` api.

In case anybody is interested my eventual solution was to use `through2-map` and `through2-reduce` to create an array.

```
...

const map = require("through2-map");
const reduce = require("through2-reduce");

...

readStream
  .pipe(converter)
  .pipe(reduce((previous, current) => {
    return previous ? `${previous},${current}` : current;
  })
  .pipe(map(chunk => `[${chunk}]`))
  .pipe(writeStream);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a late response on this.
In version `2.0.10` the JSON array format is back.

Simply set `downstreamFormat` to `json`

```js
csv({downstreamFormat:"json"}).fromFile(fileName).pipe(fileWritableStream);
```

Details can be found [here](https://github.com/Keyang/node-csvtojson#parameters)